# Android softkeyboard invoke using button click

Tags: android, keyboard

May I know is it possible to invoke android softkeyboard or Softkeyboard sample provided in the Androidsdk sample by button click? As of now I could invoke the softkeyboard only on edit view control's focus.

As per the below suggestion I did the following modification, but still didnt worked:
 here is my code.. i got error on using getContentView() so I used "v".

```
private OnClickListener mKeypadbtnListener = new OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(View v) { 
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try **imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);** instead of v.getwindowToken(). I think this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the soft keyboard issuing the following:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
                     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(getContentView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: sorry that doesnt worked for me. here is my code..
i got error on using getContentView() so I used "v". please comment
 private OnClickListener mKeypadbtnListener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(v.getWindowToken(), 0);